# How can I acces a method inside another method in the same class?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

In my code, is it possible to access method `calculate()` inside the method `calculateSheet()`? The 2 methods are in the same class.

Method `calculate()`, for example, calculates the sum of 2 doubles.
I want method `calculateSheet()`, to use this method to calculate this for every "cell" in the array `sheet[] []`.

```
//calculates every cell in the array.
public void calculateSheet() {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++) { //rows, amount of rows in the array>
        for (int j = 0 ; j < cols ; j++) { //cols, amount of colums in the array.
            sheet[i] [j].**calculate()** ; //method I want to use in the "calculateSheet" method.              
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If `calculate` is defined in the same class, you can simply call it.

Comment: Show the `calculate` method please

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need that calculations you want to do you have to put them in some variable.

Secondly I believe that you need that your calculate() method need return the result...

Assume that your method calculate is something like:

```
public double calculate(double a, double b){
    return a+b;
}
```

then you need to do something like:

```
public void calculateSheet() {
    double total = 0; //The variable when you going to put the result
    for(int i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++) { //rows, amount of rows in the array>
        for (int j = 0 ; j < cols ; j++) { //cols, amount of colums in the array.
            total += calculate(sheet[i], sheet[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets make the complete code for you,

class{

```
public double calculate(double num1, double num2){
    return (num1+num2);
}

public void calculateSheet(int[][] sheet) {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++) { 
        for (int j = 0 ; j < cols ; j++) { 
            sheet[i] [j] = calculate(i, j);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Here each cell of a 2D array will store the sum of its both indices.